# Do Axiomatic Systems Forbid Actions/Operations from Outside the Axioms? (Russell's Paradox Example)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, axioms

Are the only permissible operations/actions in an axiomatic system those that the axioms permit explicitly or through logical inference from the axioms?

---

Example:

From Jech and Hrbacek's *Introduction to Set Theory*, Page 8:

> Intuitively, sets are collections of objects sharing some common
> property, so we expect to have axioms expressing this fact. But, as
> demonstrated by the paradoxes in Section 1, not every property
> describes a set; properties "$X\not\in X$" or "$X=X$" are typical examples.

> In both cases, the problem seems to be that in order to collect all objects
> having such a property into a set, we already have to be able to perceive all sets. The difficulty is avoided if we postulate the existence of a set of all objects with a given property only if there already exists some set to which they all belong.
>
> **The Axiom Schema of Comprehension** Let **P**(x) be a property of $x$. For any set **A**, there is a set **B** such that $x\in B$ if and only if $x\in A$ and **P**(x).

As far as I can tell, the above schema allows the existence of $B$ under certain conditions. However, it does not explicitly *forbid* the existence of the proposed set from Russell's Paradox.

Comment: The origin of Russell's paradox is that if one assumes that there exists a set $X$ with $X\in X$, then one can combine that example with the system's axioms and their consequences and reach a contradiction. Such a prohibition is implicit—there's no need to have an axiom forbidding it. In general, a set of axioms will have lots of consequences, some positive, some negative. I don't think it's helpful to think of every such consequence as being stated directly by the axioms; it's much more implicit than that.

Comment: @GregMartin "The origin of Russell's paradox is that if one assumes that there exists a set $X$ with $X\in X$, then one can combine that example with the system's axioms and their consequences and reach a contradiction." That's not correct: the problem is comprehension, not self-elementhood. You don't need to assume that any set does contain itself, you just reason directly that $\{x:x\not\in x\}$ (which exists by naive comprehension) both is and is not an element of itself.

Comment: The "Russel set" is forbidden because it generates a contradiction, not because there are axioms explicitly saying it can't exist.

Comment: I think some people aren't understanding the question. We create an axiomatic system like ZF in part to eliminate the possibility that we could encounter an object like the one that comes up in Russell's Paradox. That is, we create rules for set creation which do not allow for objects such as $\{x:x\not\in x\}$. My point is that, when building an axiomatic system, it seems that inclusion of the Axiom Schema of Specification is not sufficient to eliminate the possibility of $\{x:x\not\in x\}$ unless we declare that the only allowed sets are those which the axioms or axiom schema allow.

Comment: @Gary The only sentences we're allow to assume are true when building a formal argument are the axioms, yes... that's how axiomatic theories work. How would one "declare that the only allowed sets are the ones which the axioms of axioms schema allow"? What does it mean for an axiom to "allow" something? What about a set I can define in 1000 lines of formal reasoning using 100 different axioms?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Imagine we had an axiomatic system with only one axiom: There exists a set with no elements (the "Axiom of Empty Set" from ZF). Would this axiomatic system also forbid the existence of a set $\{\varnothing\}$? If yes, then this answers my question.

Comment: No, I mean $\{\varnothing\}$. I want to understand if axiomatic systems only allow for the possible existence of objects which they provide for in their axioms, or if they allow for the possibility of the existence of other objects which they do not specify.

Comment: @Gary Sorry, I didn't see you edited your comment, I'll delete my previous. The only thing the axiom of the empty set forbids is the nonexistence of an empty set. It doesn't say or imply that $\{\emptyset\}$ doesn't exist. It would be a big problem if it did, since then we couldn't have a model in which both $\emptyset $ and $\{\emptyset\}$ exist.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I know that the Axiom of the Empty Set doesn't forbid the existence of other sets. I'm saying that if you have an axiomatic system with only that one axiom, then within that axiomatic system no other sets (including but not limited to $\{\varnothing\}$) are allowed, correct? We can only work with sets that the axioms themselves provide for?

Comment: @Gary It depends what you mean by "allowed". What *you're* not allowed to do is assume any statement that isn't an axiom (unless you've already proved it without violating this rule). With enough of the ZF axioms and enough lines of argumentation, you can prove all kinds of wild sets with wild properties exist, which aren't specifically permitted by any one axiom. But you can't do something that isn't justified by valid inference from axiom / previously proven things... I'm not sure what the alternative would be.

Comment: @Gary As for the example with just the axiom of the empty set, it's a little bit complicated by the fact that that axiom, in isolation (like without assuming extensionality, comprehension, etc) is too weak to really be *about* sets or much of anything. I think for the purposes of the discussion, the answer is basically "yes", there isn't really any other set we can define just based on this axiom (really, we can't even define the empty set. No uniqueness proof.). But the caveat here is that we needed to actually analyze the statement and observe that there weren't any nontrivial consequences.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I'm unsure about this critique, but to make sure we're on the same page, let's add Axiom of Extensionality to Axiom of the Empty Set and stop there. Our axiomatic system has only two axioms. Do you agree that in this system there exists one and only one set (the empty set)?

Comment: @Gary Since $(\{\emptyset\},\in)$ is a model of those axioms, those axioms can't prove the existence of nonempty sets. So in that sense, yes.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Is there another sense in which the answer is "no"?

Comment: @Gary The reason I am hedging with my language is you seem to be operating under the premise that a system is a collection of sets. It is a collection of statements that can be proven. Sure, some of these statements say there is a (unique) set with so and so properties, and in that sense we can say certain sets exist in a system (but really these are just definitions/existence statements we can establish on the basis of our axioms, not sets, though they will correspond to objects/sets in any model). But models of set theory in general contain many objects/sets that are not definable.